# Reshape array of images into a column vector, sorted row by row for each image

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, reshape, permute

Hello dear Matlab experts,

I have an array of images, let's say a 2 by 3 grid of images (6 images). Each image has a resolution of 4 x 4 (for simplicity). Lets say the images are grayscale.

I loaded the images into a 4D matrix with dimensions 2 x 3 x 4 x 4. Now I want to create a column vector with entries

1: first pixel of first row in image 1,1

2: second pixel of first row in image 1,1

3: ...

16: last pixel of last row in image 1, 1

17: first pixel of first row in image 2, 1

...

and so on goes the pattern. I could successfully create this with a bunch of for loops:

```
for imageX = 1 : resolution(2)
   for imageY = 1 : resolution(1)
      for pixelX = 1 : resolution(4)
         for pixelY = 1 : resolution(3)

               % linear index for 4D indices
               row = ((imageY - 1) * resolution(2) + imageX - 1) * resolution(3) * resolution(4) + ...
                   (pixelY - 1) * resolution(4) + pixelX;

               lightFieldVector(row) = lightField(imageY, imageX, pixelY, pixelX);
         end
      end
   end
end
```

I am wondering if this ugly pile of loops can be replaced by a few `reshape` and `permute` operations. I think so, but I have trouble finding the right order. I used these methods a few times, but only with 2D matrices. From the documentation I can conclude that reshaping will go 'column first', so this would be the opposite I need.

I appreciate your help,
Adrian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be the right order -

```
lightFieldVector = reshape(permute(lightField,[4 3 2 1]),[],1)
```

The whole play here is about knowing [`linear indexing`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511) and [`permute`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) in MATLAB.

---

The reverse process -

```
R = resolution
lightField = permute(reshape(lightFieldVector,R(4),R(3),R(2),R(1)),[4 3 2 1])
```

Comment: Wow, this was a very fast answer!

Comment: What about the reverse process. Would  it be like this: lightField = permute(reshape(lightFieldVector, resolution), [4, 3, 2, 1]); ?

Comment: Didn't you know that the Speed of Light was inspired after Divakar? (lol jokes). +1

Comment: The only thing slowing him down is the cable from his computer to the stackoverflow server :D

Comment: I tried it out and it works like a charm. You are my hero of the day. Now I can figure out myself to apply this with 3 color channels. Thanks man!

Comment: @aeduG haha Glad to make it *color*ful for you!